# get project template id jira

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, project-template

I'm trying to use the jira API's to create a project with a custom project template for the "projectTemplateKey" key.

The only thing I have to go on is the following links.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Create-a-project-template-in-JIRA-and-use-this-project-template/qaq-p/468079
https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/project-createProject

// This is the only reference i've found to the jira project tempalte:
https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/7.0.7/com/atlassian/jira/project/template/ProjectTemplateManager.html

Using the following bit of code to create the project.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://{HOST}/rest/api/3/project' \
  --user '{EMAIL}:{API_KEY}' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "name": "project-name",
  "description": "project-desc",
  "leadAccountId": "{LEAD_ACCOUNT_ID}",
  "url": "http://google.com",
  "projectTemplateKey": "{I_NEED_THIS-HOW_DO_I_GET_IT}",
  "assigneeType": "PROJECT_LEAD",
  "key": "LKEY",
  "projectTypeKey": "software"
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the exact same [question that was asked in Atlassian's Jira blog](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Service-Desk-questions/How-to-create-a-project-based-on-a-project-template/qaq-p/1488309) and an answer provided.

Comment: Hi there. Yeah it is. I just asked in two places as I don't always get an answer from the stack overflow community

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following SQL query:

```
select * from "AO_B9A0F0_APPLIED_TEMPLATE";
```

It will return all available Project Template Keys for your Jira.